# [Element]' requires that 'Element' inherit from 'Object'

Tags: swift, realm

I want to convert `Array<User>` to `List<User>` using this extension

```
extension Array where Element: Object {
    var asRealMList: List<Element>{
        let list = List<Element>()
        list.append(objectsIn: self)
        return list
    }
}
```

and this User class

```
class User: Object, Codable {
    convenience init(username: String) {
        self.init()
        self.username = username
    }

    @objc dynamic var username: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var displayName, displayNameAr, email, phoneNumber: String?
    @objc dynamic var department, userProfilePicture, samAccountName: String?
    let isActiveDirectoryUser = RealmOptional<Bool>()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case username = "Username"
        case displayName = "DisplayName"
        case email = "Email"
        case phoneNumber = "PhoneNumber"
        case department = "Department"
        case userProfilePicture = "ExternalUserProfilePicture"
        case samAccountName = "SamAccountName"
        case isActiveDirectoryUser
        case displayNameAr = "DisplayNameAR"
    }
}
```

but for some reason it shows compile error

> '[User]' requires that 'User' inherit from 'Object'

Comment: Check if your imports are correct. `Object` in extension file could be different from `Object` in user model

Comment: @Cerlin I just checked, and both are using realm Object

Comment: I just checked this code in my app. It works fine. :(

Comment: hmmm.. I am missing something!

Comment: the function works for all other types except User arrays

Comment: @Cerlin can you check my answer please?

Comment: The question is hard to answer because you're referencing objects in your code that are not included here. For example, in your answer you have some kind of Task object with an init but we don't know anything else about it. Your question asks about 'converting' but there's no code that 'converts' - keeping in mind that an Array and a List two very different things and while they have some similarities there are also important differences. If you can provide more info in the question we may be able to post an answer that matches

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understant why and hopefully someone here can clarify this for the rest of us
I was passing the List in init like following

```
Task(users: users.asRealmList,...)
```

but when I moved it out of init like following

```
let usersList = users.asRealmList
Task(users: usersList,...)
```

it works fine! how could this change solve the issue?

Comment: Can you add the signature of `Task` as well?

Comment: @Cerlin Agreed - this answer is useless without context of what a Task is.